# Why is Assembly.GetType() not finding my class?

Tags: c#, reflection

Code excerpt:

```
var a = Assembly.LoadFile("MyAssembly.dll");
var t = a.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass", false);
Debug.Assert(t != null); // fails
```

`Assembly.LoadFile()` is loading the assembly without any trouble, but [`Assembly.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19y21115%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is returning null, even though I have verified that `MyNamespace.MyClass` is present and correctly spelled.

Any other ideas why this is happening?

Comment: is it perhaps `internal` or an inner class or or ?

Comment: @Yahia - it is `internal`, but (a) AFAI understand that shouldn't make a difference, and (b) even when I change it to `public` it still doesn't work.  No, it's not an inner class.

Comment: is the assembly loaded when you debug it?

Comment: Waht if you set that bool 'thowOnerror' to `true`? Do you get an exception that explains the problem?

Comment: @Hohhi - `a` is not null, and I can query `a.GetName()` in the "immediate window".  So I guess that means it's loaded.

Comment: maybe "MyAssembly.dll" isn't the path to the *last version* of your assembly or "MyNamespace.MyClass" is incorrect.

Comment: @Shaul `internal` wouldn't work that way... what happens when you call `GetTypes()` and inspect the result - do you see the "missing" Type ?

Comment: @Hans Kesting - that was a very helpful suggestion.  I set it to throw an exception, and the exception tells me that `MyAssembly.dll` has another dependency, which apparently I need to reference.  Please put that as an answer and I'll credit you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the line

```
var t = a.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass", false);
```

set that boolean to `true` so you get an exception that could explain the problem. For various problem situations you get separate exceptions, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19y21115.aspx) or the new [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype#System_Type_GetType_System_String_System_Boolean_).

Comment: Thank you!  This is what solved my problem; I will post the root of the problem as a separate answer.

Comment: What was the message you got that helped you solved the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The actual underlying problem was that `MyAssembly.dll` has another dependency on `OtherAssembly.dll`.  Once I include a reference to `OtherAssembly.dll` in the calling assembly, everything works fine.

Comment: @Oskar - I posted it because the credited answer was about *how* to find the problem; my answer is *what* the problem was, so I thought it worthwhile to post separately.

Comment: How did you know what other assembly to load?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Retrieve all classes that are typeof SomeClassOrInterface

List<Type> myTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(typeof(SomeClassOrInterface).IsAssignableFrom).ToList();

// Loop thru them or just use Active.CreateInstance() of the type you need

myTypes.ForEach(myType => {
    SomeClassOrInterface instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType) as SomeClassOrInterface;                           
});
```

This code sample works under .NET 4